# `stream.Transform.unshift()` in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, coffeescript

Consider simple example:

```
stream = require 'stream'
util = require 'util'

class TestTransform extends stream.Transform
    _transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        if not @noMore
            @noMore = true
            @unshift chunk # I will handle you later
        else
            @push " <#{chunk.toString().toUpperCase()}>"
        callback()

mt = new TestTransform()
mt.write 'first'
mt.write 'second'
mt.on 'data', (chunk) -> console.log "data: #{util.inspect chunk.toString()}"
```

> ```
> $ coffee test.coffee
> data: 'first <SECOND>'
> ```

This transform stream tries to push back it's first chunk back into read queue, so it will be handled in next `_transform` call.

But for some reason, `unshift`ing in `Transform` causes data to immediately go into output without getting into `_transform` again (and hence not uppercased). Is that intentionally or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`unshift` is a `Readable` method.  This means that when you call it on a transform, you're pushing stuff back into output-side buffer, not the input-side.

Don't do this.  Since you have no way of knowing how much is in the output-side buffer, this essentially pushes data in a non-deterministic order.